# MetaMask - RPC Error: Permissions request already pending, in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, angular10, metamask

I have integrated the MetaMask with Angular and while opening up the MetaMask extension from the code I am getting this error.

Following is my code for opening up the extension.
I am calling this function on a click to open MetaMask where its giving that error

**MetaMask - RPC Error: Permissions request already pending; please wait. {code: -32002, message: "Permissions request already pending; please wait."}**

```
ethEnabled(template?): any
  {
    if ((window as any).web3)
    {
      (window as any).web3 = new Web3((window as any).web3.currentProvider);
      (window as any).ethereum.enable();
      console.log((window as any).ethereum.enable());

    }
    else
    {
      this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

This error is actually expected; it happens when you've already submitted a permissions request, but the user has either not logged into MetaMask or not granted permissions to your app.

If the user logs into MetaMask and accepts the permissions request, this error will not occur anymore.

This is explained in the [docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#connecting-to-metamask), where it says `You should always disable the "connect" button while the connection request is pending` (otherwise this error occurs).

Here is one way to handle this:

- Disable the button while the request is pending
- If the user is not connected after a certain waiting period (10-20 seconds, perhaps?), show a message under the button requesting the user to complete the MetaMask connection.

There is more information and a nice example in [their docs here](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#connecting-to-metamask).

Answer (score 0):

Describe the bug

When I close the unlock wallet popup while requesting eth accounts, I'm not getting any result. And when I request eth accounts again, I'm getting the following error MetaMask - RPC Error: Already processing eth_requestAccounts. Please wait.

Steps to reproduce (REQUIRED)

```
 window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
 const account = await window.ethereum.request({
      method: 'eth_requestAccounts',
 })
```

Have wallet locked
Trigger request
Close unlock popup
Trigger request again
Expected behavior

Receive error with specific code to know that unlock wallet has been closed as well as the transaction to be discharged from the processing pipe.

Answer (score -1):

Clear your internet cache, temp files etc.

Comment: As part of your answer, you should provide an example of how to accomplish *"Clear your internet cache, temp files etc."*.

Comment: This answer says nothing